# Convert Binary to Hexadecimal in Java without methods

Tags: java

I am currently a beginner in programming and I am trying to write a program in java to convert binary in hexadecimal numbers.
I know that the program will have to divide the number in groups of 4 and convert them to hexadecimal.
Ex: 11101111 (b2) -->  E + F --- EF
However, since I used ints to do the conversion of the numbers, I'm stuck when I need to print a letter because it is a String.

Can someone point me to the right way? What am I doing wrong? I've also tried another version with an auxiliary array to store each group of 4 digits but I can't manage to insert a proper dimension to the array.

Unfortunately I am not allowed to use any function other than Scanner and Math, the method lenght and charAt and the basic stuff. I can't modify the public static line either.

**EDIT:** So after your inputs and so many tries, I managed to get this code. However it gives me an error if I insert too many numbers, eg: 0111011010101111. I've tried to change int to double but that didn't fix the problem.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bin2HexString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Valor?");
        int vlr = keyb.nextInt();

        String num = "";
        int aux = vlr;

        // Hexadecimal numbers
        String arr[] = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
        String bits[] = {"0000","0001","0010","0011","0100","0101","0110","0111","1000","1001","1010","1011","1100","1101","1110","1111"};

        String letters = "";
        //Divide in groups of 4
        int r;
        for (; aux > 0; ) {
            r = aux % 10000;
            aux = aux / 10000;
            num = "" + r;
            for (;num.length() < 4;) { //add missing zeros
                String zero = "0";
                num = zero + num;
            }
            int charint = 0,bitint = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length;i++) { 
                String aux2 = bits[i];
                String aux3 = arr[i];
                for (int j = 0; j < num.length();j++) { // compare each group with arr[i]
                    char charvl = num.charAt(j);
                    char bitsvl = aux2.charAt(j);
                    charint = ((int) (charvl)-'0');
                    bitint = ((int) (bitsvl) - '0');
                    if (bitint != charint)
                        break;

                }
                if (bitint == charint)
                    letters = aux3 + "" + letters;

            }

        }
        System.out.println(letters);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Note that, internally, everything is binary already.  You don't have to do anything to make code "binary."

Comment: Are you trying to convert an `int value` into `hex` or a binary string representation into a hex representation?

Comment: @markspace I wasn't trying to make the code binary, I tried to divide the user input in groups of four because it is required before converting to hexadecimal

Comment: @WJS it doesn't matter if the user binary input is an int or string as long as I can convert it to hex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having thought about this for a while to determine the most effective and useful way to do this is to write methods which convert a `string` from any base between `2` and `16` to an `int` and back to a `string` again.

This way you have useful methods for other things.  And note that they methods can be easily changed and names to simply hard code the desired `radix` into the method to limit it to `binary` and `hex` methods.

The `indexOf` utility method was written to avoid using the builtin String method.

```java
   final static String hex = "0123456789ABCDEF";

   static int stringToInt(String str, int radix) {
      if (radix < 2 || radix > 16) {
         System.out.println("Base must be between 2 and 16 inclusive");
         return -1;
      }
      int v = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
         char c = str.charAt(i);
         int idx = indexOf(hex, c);
         if (idx < 0 || idx > radix) {
            System.out.println("Illegal character in string (" + c + ")");
         }
         v = v * radix + idx;
      }
      return v;
   }

   static String intToBase(int v, int radix) {
      if (radix < 2 || radix > 16) {
         System.out.println("Base must be between 2 and 16 inclusive");
         return null;
      }
      String s = "";
      while (v > 0) {
         int idx = v % radix;
         s = hex.charAt(idx) + s;
         v /= radix;
      }
      return s;
   }

   static int indexOf(String str, char c) {
      for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
         if (str.charAt(i) == c) {
            return i;
         }
      }
      return -1;
   }
```

And here is an example of their use.

```java
      // generate some test data
      Random r = new Random(23);
      String[] bitStrings =
            r.ints(20, 20, 4000).mapToObj(Integer::toBinaryString).toArray(
                  String[]::new);

      for (String bitstr : bitStrings) {
         int v = baseToInt(bitstr, 2);
         String hex = intToBase(v, 16);
         System.out.printf("%12s = %s%n", bitstr, hex);
      }
```

Which prints the following:

```
101110000011 = B83
111001111100 = E7C
 10001110111 = 477
100110001111 = 98F
   111001010 = 1CA
111001001111 = E4F
111000011010 = E1A
100001010010 = 852
 11011001101 = 6CD
111010010111 = E97
```

Answer (score 1):

Just some quick notes:

First this is wrong:

```
//Divide in groups of 4
for (; aux > 0; ) {
   r = aux % 10000;
   aux = aux / 10000;
```

Not at all what you want to do.  Try it by hand and see what happens.  Take a simple number that you know the answer to, and try it.  You won't get the right answer.  A good test is 17, which is 11 hex.

Try this instead: convert directly to the base you want.  Hex is base 16 (its *radix* is 16), so you use 16 instead.

```
//Divide in groups of 4
for (; aux > 0; ) {
  r = aux % 16;
  aux = aux / 16;
```

Try those numbers with the test case, which is 17, and see what you get.  That will get you much closer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by "without methods" in the title, you are attempting to write your own integer parsing method instead of using `Scanner.nextInt(int radix)`. In that case, my first advice would be work with a string instead of an integer - you'll be able to handle larger numbers and you can simply make an array of substrings (length 4) to convert to letters.

So, if you use the string approach - first scan in a string, not an int. Then I'd recommend a hash table with the 4-bit strings as keys and the hexadecimal equivalents as values. That should make calculation quite fast.

e.g.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HashMapBin2Hex
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    //Read the string in
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Binary number?");
    String bin = sc.nextLine();
    //Pad the bitstring with leading zeros to make a multiple of four
    String zeros = "";
    int i;
    if (bin.length() % 4 != 0)
    {
      for (i = 0; i < 4 - (bin.length() % 4); i++)
      {
        zeros += "0";
      }
    }
    bin = zeros + bin;
    //Split the padded string into 4-bit chunks
    String[] chunks = new String[bin.length() / 4];
    for (i = 0; (i * 4) < bin.length() - 1; i++)
    {
      chunks[i] = bin.substring(i * 4, (i * 4) + 4);
    }
    //Convert the chunks to hexadecimal
    String hex = "";
    Map<String, String> bin2hex = new HashMap<>();
    bin2hex.put("0000", "0");
    bin2hex.put("0001", "1");
    bin2hex.put("0010", "2");
    bin2hex.put("0011", "3");
    bin2hex.put("0100", "4");
    bin2hex.put("0101", "5");
    bin2hex.put("0110", "6");
    bin2hex.put("0111", "7");
    bin2hex.put("1000", "8");
    bin2hex.put("1001", "9");
    bin2hex.put("1010", "A");
    bin2hex.put("1011", "B");
    bin2hex.put("1100", "C");
    bin2hex.put("1101", "D");
    bin2hex.put("1110", "E");
    bin2hex.put("1111", "F");
    for (String s : chunks)
    {
      hex += bin2hex.get(s);
    }
    System.out.println("Hexadecimal: " + hex);
    sc.close();
  }
}
```

Further iterations could have some error checking to prevent catastrophic failure in the case of characters other than 0 or 1.

And of course, if you're fine with the other way (builtins), the following is far easier and more robust (ie will throw an exception if the string contains anything other than 0s and 1s):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BuiltinBin2Hex
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    //Read the binary number in
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Binary number?");
    int bin = sc.nextInt(2);
    //And print as hexadecimal
    System.out.println("Hexadecimal: " + Integer.toString(bin, 16));
    sc.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Unfortunatelly I can't use any function other than Scanner or Math and I'm not allowed to use substrings yet.. That's why I'm struggling so much to do this. However after seeing your code I am trying to do the code all over again but now only using arrays and strings. The problem that I am facing now is extracting groups of 4 from the user input string without substring.

Comment: Why do you keep trying to extract a group of four?  Some hex numbers have other numbers of digits.  1 is a hex number.  1C is a hex number, it has two digits.  Why always four?

Comment: *I can't use any function other than Scanner or Math*.  You're using `String.length()` and `String.charAt()`.  So you need to be specific.  Can you use `String.toCharArray()`?  Can you use `String.indexOf()`?

Comment: @WJS I'm sorry, that's my bad, I've corrected the post. The only two that I didn't mention was charAt and length.

Comment: @markspace My teacher told me to convert binary to hex in groups of 4 digits, that's why I tried it that way. I've updated the code and it seems to work as long as I don't insert too many numbers, so I'm trying to fix that.

Comment: We should see some actual input and output, otherwise we don't know what's going on.  Real hex numbers don't always come in groups of four.

Comment: @markspace Although hex numbers can be any length, a group of 4 binary bits corresponds to a single hex digit. Thus, if you convert 4 _binary_ digits at a time, you can simply line them up in the same order and that conserves the value.

Comment: @RockLife I saw your edit. If you'd like to continue with that code and support larger binary numbers, use a long instead of an int. (up to 18 digits instead of 10) Otherwise, I'd go with the answer by WJS which I believe fits the requirements for method use.